# How to set "return_value" once for TestCase. Python. Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Here is example test:

```
import a
import b
import c

import mock
from django.test import TestCase

@mock.patch.object(a, "method_a")
@mock.patch.object(b, "method_b")
@mock.patch.object(c, "method_c")
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # I want to set mock_method_a.return_value = 1 once here (or not here, but once)
        pass

    def test_one(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        mock_method_a.return_value = 1
        mock_method_b.return_value = 2
        pass  # some test stuff

    def test_two(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        mock_method_a.return_value = 1
        mock_method_b.return_value = 2
        pass  # some test stuff

    def test_three(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        mock_method_a.return_value = 1
        mock_method_b.return_value = 2
        pass  # some test stuff
```

**Queston**:

How I can avoid of duplicate code for setting "return_value" in each test in TestCase?


I expect something in "setUp" method or something similar.

Is it possible?

PS: mock version mock==1.3.0, django version Django==1.8.4

Comment: Why *not* in `setUp`? You can actually set the return value when you create the patch, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `return_value` right there in the `@mock.patch.object()` decorators:

```
@mock.patch.object(c, "method_c", return_value=3)
@mock.patch.object(b, "method_b", return_value=2)
@mock.patch.object(a, "method_a", return_value=1)
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_one(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        # do test stuff, return values have been set

    def test_two(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        # do test stuff, return values have been set

    def test_three(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        # do test stuff, return values have been set
```

(Note: when decorating with `@mock.patch` the decorators are applied from the bottom on up, so for `mock_method_a` to be passed in as the first argument you need to put the decorator closest to the class definition).

The `return_value` keyword argument to `mock.patch.object()` is passed to the `MagicMock()` constructor. See the [`mock.patch.object()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object):

> Like `patch()`, `patch.object()` takes arbitrary keyword arguments for configuring the mock object it creates.

and the [`mock.Mock` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock):

> `Mock` takes several optional arguments that specify the behaviour of the `Mock` object:
>
> - *[...]*
> - `return_value`: The value returned when the mock is called. By default this is a new `Mock` (created on first access). See the `return_value` attribute.

If you also want to avoid setting the mocks *outside* of your test case or don't like the additional arguments to each test function, then you you can also can create *patchers* in the `setUp` method, which then are removed again when the test ends by registering a callback via the [`unittest.TestCase.addCleanup()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup).

The patchers are applied for each test, by calling [the `patcher.start()` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop), which returns the new mock object:

```
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        patcher_method_a = mock.patch.object(a, "method_a")
        self.mock_method_a = patcher_method_a.start()
        self.mock_method_a.return_value = 1

        patcher_method_b = mock.patch.object(b, "method_b")
        self.mock_method_b = patcher_method_b.start()
        self.mock_method_b.return_value = 2

        patcher_method_c = mock.patch.object(c, "method_c")
        self.mock_method_c = patcher_method_c.start()
        self.mock_method_c.return_value = 3

        # when the test is done, stop **all** patchers
        self.addCleanup(mock.patch.stopall)

    def test_one(self):
        # use self.mock_method_a, etc.

    def test_two(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        # use self.mock_method_a, etc.

    def test_three(self, mock_method_a, mock_method_b, mock_method_c):
        # use self.mock_method_a, etc.
```

Note that the `mock.patch.stopall()` method will stop *all mock patchers that have started*. You can also pass the `.stop` attributes of each of the patchers:

```
self.addCleanup(patcher_method_a.stop)
self.addCleanup(patcher_method_b.stop)
self.addCleanup(patcher_method_c.stop)
```

If you have to create a lot of such setups, you could create a helper function that'll take care of the repeated parts:

```
def setup_object_patch(testcase, object, target, return_value, attrname=None):
    patcher = mock.patch.object(object, target)
    mock = patcher.start()
    mock.return_value = return_value
    setattr(testcase, attrname or f'mock_{target}', mock)
    testcase.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
```

and perhaps use this in a loop over a mapping:

```
def setUp(self):
    mocks = {
        # attribute name on test -> object, target, return_value
        'mock_method_a': (a, 'method_a', 1),
        'mock_method_b': (b, 'method_b', 2),
        'mock_method_c': (c, 'method_c', 3),
    }
    for attrname, params in mocks.items():
        setup_object_patch(*params, attrname=attrname)
```

The `patcher.start()` approach in a `TestCase.setUp()` method makes it easier to use *inheritance*, where a base testcase case is used as the basis for several test cases that all use the same shared mocking setup.

Comment: the patch decorator in the order `a b c`,  the mock methods should be in the order of  `mock_c, mock_b, mock_a` in theory, right?

Comment: @Gang: yes, note that the OP got this wrong in their example too. I'll correct.